# Which controll to use to display SMS messages in android

Tags: android, sms

I am creating a SMS application in Android, As i am very new to android can any one tell me which control to use to display the messages (`ListView` or `TableView` or any other).

The requirement is that the used control must be able to refresh itself when a new message comes.

Comment: Do you search for this in goole?

Comment: Follow that http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ListView, most SMS apps use ListView take a look at open source app [here](https://github.com/felixb/smsdroid/blob/master/SMSdroid/src/main/java/de/ub0r/android/smsdroid/MessageListActivity.java)

Comment: is it possible to refresh the list view when a new message comes without distracting the user?

Comment: You should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14097569/2135888 this should show you how to implement your listview to display sms messages using content providers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089313/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages here you can listen for a new sms if you need this, but I would not bother with this. I belive I have never been in sms app while I received another.

Comment: My application is not just a simple SMS application, I am using Steganography technique to embed the message into an image and i use a server to exchange messages. I just need to learn to update List view(If I use as you suggested) when a new message is found in server. Thanks a lot for your help and time. I will go through the posts which you suggested.