# Hide sms from inbox completely and fastly in eclipse

Tags: android, sms, message, inbox

[How to read sms and work on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097500/get-inbox-messages-from-android-device-to-show-in-custom-listview)

This link is how to read sms but i have a question!

How can messages be hidden to fast in inbox?
If we want hidden messages, what to do?
Is their a command for it?!
If we read all messages, copy it and then delete it, it would be very slow if messages are a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find it.
 my answer:
without root access, it's impossible.
if root access, to hide all sms I can rename mmssms.db to another and then when i want to show it remane it again