# simplecursoradapter/listview to sqlite database

Tags: android, android-listview, sms, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

Hi I'm very new to database. I've a code to retrieve SMS Inbox, Sent Box and Draft from phone and show it in a ListView using SimpleCursor Adapter. I want to save and retrieve ListView items (one at a time) of "Sent Box" to SQLite database. Currently I can insert data into database using edittext values. So basically what I want is a method to select ListView item one at a time and save it in String[] and then insert String[] value to database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
Code to display database items using "ListActivity"

SQLiteDatabase db;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
         db=openOrCreateDatabase("Student.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);         
         Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select id,name,age from Stud", null);
            ArrayList<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>();
         
            int count=c.getCount();
                      
            if(c.getCount()>0)
            {
                while(c.moveToNext())
             {
               list.add(c.getString(0)+" , "+c.getString(1)+" , "+c.getString(2));
                }                
             c.close();
             Toast.makeText(this,"Total Records: "+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
             getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {
             Toast.makeText(this, "No Record Found" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         Toast.makeText(this, ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  db.close();
 }
}
```

```css
SQLite database

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  
 SQLiteDatabase db; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createDB();
      //do insert
  Button btnInsert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInsert );
        btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    
    insert();
   }
  });
        Button btnClear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear );
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
   public void onClick(View arg0) {    
    clear();
   }
  });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     CreateMenu(menu);
     return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
     return MenuChoice(item);
    }
  
    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
    {
     MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Insert");
     {
      mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('i');
      mnu1.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
     }
     MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search");
     {
      mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('s');
      mnu2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);
      
     }
     MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Delete");
     {
      mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
      mnu3.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

     }
     MenuItem mnu4 = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "View");
     {
      mnu4.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
      mnu4.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
     }
     }
    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
    {
     Intent intent=new Intent();
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case 0:
       insert();
       return true;
      case 1:
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
      case 2:
       intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
       return true;

      case 3:
       intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ViewRecord.class);
       startActivity(intent);  
          return true;

     }
     return false;
    }
    public void createDB()
 {  
  db=openOrCreateDatabase("Student.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
  db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
  db.setLockingEnabled(true);
  db.setVersion(1);
  String sql="create table if not exists Stud(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, age INTEGER)";
  db.execSQL(sql);
 }
 public void insert()
 {  
   EditText txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
   EditText txtAge=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
   if(txtName.getText().toString().equals(""))
   {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   else if (txtAge.getText().toString().equals(""))
   {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Age.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else
   {
  
    String sql="insert into Stud(name,age) values('"+ txtName.getText().toString() +"',"+txtAge.getText().toString()+")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    clear();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Record Successfully Inserted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }    
 }
 public void clear()
 {
  EditText txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
   EditText txtAge=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
  txtName.setText("");
  txtAge.setText("");
   
  txtName.clearFocus();
  txtAge.clearFocus();
  txtName.requestFocus();
  
 
 }
 @Override
    public void onDestroy()
 {
  super.onDestroy();
  db.close();
 }
}
```

```html
Code for displaying SMS Inbox, Sent Box and Draft

public class MessageBox extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 // GUI Widget
 Button btnSent, btnInbox, btnDraft;
 TextView lblMsg, lblNo;
 ListView lvMsg;

 // Cursor Adapter
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.messagebox);

  // Init GUI Widget
  btnInbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInbox);
  btnInbox.setOnClickListener(this);

  btnSent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSentBox);
  btnSent.setOnClickListener(this);

  btnDraft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDraft);
  btnDraft.setOnClickListener(this);

  lvMsg = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMsg);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  if (v == btnInbox) {

   // Create Inbox box URI
   Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

   // List required columns
   String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

   // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
   // Provider
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

   // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
   Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

   // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
     new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
       R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
   lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

  }

  if (v == btnSent) {

   // Create Sent box URI
   Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

   // List required columns
   String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

   // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
   // Provider
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

   // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
   Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

   // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
     new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
       R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
   lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

  }

  if (v == btnDraft) {
   // Create Draft box URI
   Uri draftURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");

   // List required columns
   String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

   // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
   // Provider
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

   // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
   Cursor c = cr.query(draftURI, reqCols, null, null, null);

   // Attached Cursor with adapter and display in listview
   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, c,
     new String[] { "body", "address" }, new int[] {
       R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber });
   lvMsg.setAdapter(adapter);

  }

 }
}
```

Comment: no one with any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the SMS data from the following code

```
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

        // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
        // Provider
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        // Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
        Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```

Now all you need to do is get the data from cursor and insert it in your database either using raw query as you are doing or by using Content Provider.

For more information read [Get inbox messages from android device to show in custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097500/get-inbox-messages-from-android-device-to-show-in-custom-listview)