# Is it possible to check if SMS has been received in a xamarin ui test

Tags: android, ios, sms, xamarin.uitest

The app I am currently testing sends an SMS to the phone after answering some questions with a code to enter. Is it possible to check that the SMS has been received on the phone and the contents of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on iOS.
For Android it's possible, and you have already some answers about it, 
such as:

[How to read the message content of a new in coming message in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007332/how-to-read-the-message-content-of-a-new-in-coming-message-in-android)

or

[How can I read SMS messages from the device programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-device-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: I am not using Android studio I am using Xamarin UI Test to create the tests. I do not have access to the source code so this is not what I was asking. @Roee84